# Checking that multiple asynchronous functions have completed before drawing a d3 chart

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, d3.js

**Context:** I'm attempting to query the [CrisisNET API](http://crisis.net/) multiple times, to find the number of reports that were filed each day in a range of days.

**Question:** how do check that all asynchronous functions have completed before using the  totals array to draw a d3 chart?

**Code:**

```
var format = d3.time.format.iso,
    min = format.parse('2014-06-01'),
    max = format.parse('2014-07-01'),
    range = d3.time.day.utc.range(min, max);

totals = [];

for (var i = 0; i < range.length - 1; i++) {

    var request = (function(before, after) {

        var url = 'http://api.crisis.net/item?'
            + '&before=' + format(before)
            + '&after=' + format(after)
            + '&placeName=Syria'
            + '&limit=0'
            + '&apikey=[apikey]';

        d3.json(url, function(error, data) {

            var total =  {

                'date': after,
                'total': data.total

            };

            totals.push(total);
        });
    }(range[i + 1], range[i]));
}
```

Thank you in advance for any help. I'm a relative newcomer to JavaScript and am still trying to understand callbacks, asynchronous functions, and the like.

Comment: You could do this with jQuery's promises -- but I notice that you didn't tag jQuery so we'll avoid that...

Comment: I'm not averse to using jQuery, but wondered whether I was missing a more obvious solution! @CaseyFalk

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know how many functions you're expecting to have done, and you have a callback on each one, you can use a wrapper function to count them and execute something else once they've all executed. Something like this:

```
function asyncCounter(numCalls, callback){
    this.callback = callback;
    this.numCalls = numCalls;
    this.calls = 0;
};

asyncCounter.prototype.increment = function(){
    if(this.calls++ === this.numCalls){
        this.callback();
    }
};
```

You then create an `asyncCounter` object and increment it each time you read a JSON:

```
var myAsyncCounter = new asyncCounter(numCallsExpected, callback);

...//code outside the JSON calls
d3.json(url, function(error, data) {
    ... //code you want to execute before incrementing the counter
    myAsyncCounter.increment();
}
```

`callback` will execute after all of the code in the `d3.json` calls has finished.

Comment: Should you not store `callback` in `this.callback`? I tested your code as written, and it returned a ReferenceError.

Comment: Whoops, you're right. `callback` should be `this.callback`. That's what I get for not testing my code :)

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I've come up with so far. It works, but I'm sure there must be a better way!

```
var format = d3.time.format.iso,
    min = format.parse('2014-06-01'),
    max = format.parse('2014-07-01'),
    range = d3.time.day.utc.range(min, max);

totals = [];

for (var i = 0; i < range.length - 1; i++) {

    var request = (function(before, after) {

        var url = 'http://api.crisis.net/item?'
            + '&before=' + format(before)
            + '&after=' + format(after)
            + '&placeName=Syria'
            + '&limit=0'
            + '&apikey=[apikey]';

        d3.json(url, function(error, data) {

            var total =  {

                'date': after,
                'total': data.total

            };

            totals.push(total);

            ready();
        });
    }(range[i + 1], range[i]));
}

function ready() {

    if (totals.length === range.length - 1) {
        // Draw chart here
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could create a callback for when the data is loaded, and a variable for the number of times it has been called. Then when the number of calls equals the number of items that must be in the dataset, you are ready to make your visualization:

```
var itemsLoaded = 0;
function dataLoaded() {
  itemsLoaded++;
  if (itemsLoaded === range.length - 1) {
    createVisualization();
  }
}
```

Then inside your d3.json callback, you can call `dataLoaded` after an item has been pushed into `totals`:

```
d3.json(url, function(error, data) {
  var total =  {
    'date': after,
    'total': data.total
  };
  totals.push(total);
  dataLoaded();
});
```

If the order of the elements in `totals` is really important to you, you might want to use the index explicitly rather than `.push`ing them into the array:

```
d3.json(url, function(error, data) {
  var total =  {
    'date': after,
    'total': data.total
  };
  totals[i] = total;
  dataLoaded();
});
```

Also, be careful with your syntax when evaluating the function for the variable `request`. You need to make sure you are evaluating the expression first, and then calling it.

Instead of this...

```
var request = (function(before, after) {/*...*/}(range[i+1], range[i]));
```

... it should look like this (look at the parens):

```
var request = (function(before, after) {/*...*/})(range[i+1], range[i]);
```

Comment: The order isn't too important, as I can always sort `totals` in the callback function. I followed "JavaScript: The Good Parts" (p.37) for the closure syntax. What are the implications of your first snippet? I haven't come across your suggestion before.

Comment: I'm going to accept the answer given by @ckersh, as it encapsulates both the counter and the callback. Thank you for your suggestions, though.

Comment: Hmm... You're right. I guess I've just never seen it done that first way. I've always wrapped the function in parens and then called it. Both give the same result, but I wonder if there's any advantage/disadvantage to one way or the other. Thanks for the JS Good Parts reference.